# Aggregation on a Dataset with composite keys

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-dataset

My input dataset looks like ds[(T, U)]. Where T and U both looks like below.

```
T => (key1, key2, ...) and U => (value1, value2, ...)
```

The aggregation looks like

```
ds.groupBy("key1", "key2", ...)
      .agg(
        sum("value1")).alias("value11"),
        sum("value2")).alias("value22"),
        ...
      .select("key1", "key2", ..., "value11", "value22", "fileId", ...)
```

which is final output.
Is there a better way to achieve the same output by using groupByKey/reduceGroups or something else in terms of performance?

The inout dataset is generated by processing rows. we have nested objects inside a row which we loop through to extract the keys and values from each row. What is the efficient way to combine both the process together? Would custom UDAF be better to go for this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of performance this is as good as it gets. Using statically typed `Dataset` and `groupByKey` / `reduceGroups` can only degrade performance or at best, provide no improvement whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What is your opinion about using UDAF? Is this scenario suitable for udaf?